# Move files of multiple extensions in a loop using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want some files of specific extensions to move to a destination directory. Here is the portion of my batch file:

```
move "%filepath%\*.txt" "%~dp0"
move "%filepath%\*.docx" "%~dp0"
move "%filepath%\*.pdf" "%~dp0"
move "%filepath%\*.jpg" "%~dp0"
move "%filepath%\*.png" "%~dp0"
```

The above code works fine. But I want to do so in a loop. I am trying like the following:

```
set f_ext=*.txt *.docx *.pdf *.jpg *.png
for %%f in (%f_ext%) do (
    move "%filepath%\%%f" "%~dp0"
)
```

The above code works only if there are already the files of same names in the destination folder (`%~dp0`), but it does not work otherwise.

So how to move files of some extensions in a loop using batch that does not require the filenames exist in the destination folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the wildcards in the `for` make it iterate over the files in the current active directory

```dos
set f_ext=.txt .docx .pdf .jpg .png
for %%f in (%f_ext%) do (
    move "%filepath%\*%%f" "%~dp0"
)
```

Change the wildcard from the `for` (remove them from the set of extensions) into the `move` command.